# Invalid results in merge sort application

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Hello I am working on an application of the merge sort algorithm however after a few hours I am unable to find a solution. Any help or hint would be appreciated. I have tried to debug my code but after many attempts I have not been successful in seeing what the mistake is.

The problem is that the algorithm gives back a wrong result. Example:
input: `(10, 5, 16, 2)`
output: `(2, 5, 5, 10)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergesort(int A[], int l, int r);
void merge(int A[], int l, int q, int r);

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int tablica[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &tablica[i]);

    mergesort(tablica, 0, n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", tablica[i]);

    return 0;
}

void mergesort(int A[], int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int q = (l + r) / 2;
        mergesort(A, l, q);
        mergesort(A, q + 1, r);
        merge(A, l, q, r);
    }
}

void merge(int A[], int l, int q, int r) {
    int n = q - l + 1;
    int m = r - q;

    int B[n];
    int C[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        B[i] = A[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        C[i] = A[q + 1 + i];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = l; k <= r; k++) {
        if (B[i] <= C[j] || j >= m) {
            A[k] = B[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            A[k] = C[j];
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create the smallest possible input set that causes the problem, and hard-code it into your application. Then use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. That's the usual way to solve problems similar to this.

Comment: @DamianKowalski: can you please accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what exactly doesn't work (Does it not compile? Do you get wrong output for some inputs?) it's hard to help. At least one error is here:

```
if(B[i] <= C[j] || j >= m)
```

Should be

```
if(j >= m || i < n && B[i] <= C[j])
```

It is both important to check `j >= m` before you check the inequality, and add the `i < n` check.

Without the latter once you fully consume the `B` array, `B[i]` will go beyond the array boundaries, and you will get undefined behavior.

Without the former once `j >= m` the condition `B[i] <= C[j]` will be checked before `j >= m`, also triggering undefined behavior.

*UPDATE:* with the actual example you provided, the second error narrows down to replacing `B[i] = A[i]` with `B[i] = A[l + i]`. With these two changes the example you provided works.

Answer (score 1):

The function `merge` has several bugs.

For example the size of the array C shall be calculated like

```
int m = r - q + 1;
```

instead of

```
int m = r - q;
```

Instead of this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    B[i] = A[i];
```

you have to write

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    B[i] = A[l + i];
```

This if statement

```
if(B[i] <= C[j] || j >= m)
```

can result in undefined behavior because there is no check of the validity of the used indices i and j whether they belong to the valid ranges.

The functions can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void merge( int a[], size_t left, size_t middle, size_t right )
{
    size_t n1 = middle - left;
    size_t n2 = right - middle;
    int a1[n1];
    int a2[n2];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
    {
        a1[i] = a[left + i];
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ )
    {
        a2[i] = a[middle + i];
    }
    
    size_t i = left, i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    
    while ( i1 < n1 && i2 < n2 )
    {
        a[i++] = a2[i2] < a1[i1] ? a2[i2++] : a1[i1++];
    }
    
    while ( i1 < n1 ) a[i++] = a1[i1++];
    while ( i2 < n2 ) a[i++] = a2[i2++];
}

void mergesort( int a[], size_t left, size_t right )
{
    if ( left + 1 < right )
    {
        size_t middle = ( left + right ) / 2;
        mergesort( a, left, middle );
        mergesort( a, middle, right );
        merge( a, left, middle, right );
    }       
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n;
    
    if ( scanf( "%zu", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        int a[n];
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", a + i );
    
        mergesort( a, 0, n );
        
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
4
10 5 16 2
```

then the output will be

```
2 5 10 16
```

Comment: Minor `( left + right ) / 2` may overflow.  `left + (right - left)/2` does not.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the `merge` function:

`if (B[i] <= C[j] || j >= m)` accesses `B[i]` and `C[j]` before testing if `i` and `j` are below their respective boundaries. The test should be:

```
    if (i < n && (j >= m || B[i] <= C[j])) {
        A[k] = B[i++];
    } else {
        A[k] = C[j++];
    }
```

Note also these remarks:

- you do not need to save the second half of the array because its elements are copied before they get overwritten.
- in `void mergesort(int A[], int l, int r)` `r` should be excluded, to avoid confusing and error prone `+1`/`-1` adjustments.
- similarly, in `void merge(int A[], int l, int q, int r)`, `q` should be the start of the second half and `r` the index of the element after the end of the slice.
- `l` looks confusingly similar to `1`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mergesort(int A[], int low, int high);
void merge(int A[], int low, int mid, int high);

int main() {
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0)
        return 1;

    int tablica[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (scanf("%d", &tablica[i]) != 1)
           return 1;
    }
    mergesort(tablica, 0, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", tablica[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void mergesort(int A[], int low, int high) {
    if (high - low >= 2) {
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        mergesort(A, low, mid);
        mergesort(A, mid, high);
        merge(A, low, mid, high);
    }
}

void merge(int A[], int low, int mid, int high) {
    int n = mid - low;
    int B[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        B[i] = A[low + i];

    int i = 0;
    int j = mid;
    int k = low;

    while (i < n) {
        if (j >= high || B[i] <= A[j]) {
            A[k++] = B[i++];
        } else {
            A[k++] = C[j++];
        }
    }
}
```